# Why struct buffer do not need to initialize

Tags: go

I am trying to use Buffer package and copy the following code from Buffer documentation.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    var b bytes.Buffer // A Buffer needs no initialization.
    b.Write([]byte("Hello "))
    fmt.Fprintf(&b, "world!")
    b.WriteTo(os.Stdout)
}
```

Why do Buffer here, not to be initialize?

Comment: I made my own example, to clarify http://play.golang.org/p/eXHY0VaqzJ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://golang.org/src/pkg/bytes/buffer.go?s=402:854#L7) Buffer consists just of some ints, the buf slice and some arrays. All of them need no initialization, since go has [zero values](http://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value).

You can read more about slices and arrays and how they work [here](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals).

Comment: why I have to pass &b address in function call `fmt.Fprintf(&b, "world!")`. When I watch Fprintf documentation, it does not expect a pointer.

Comment: fmt.Fprintf expects an io.Writer as first parameter. (*Buffer).Write is the method on the pointer, so *Buffer is an io.Writer while Buffer is not.

Comment: Can you please make your own example

Comment: see http://play.golang.org/p/dHgvZPNomJ
If you uncomment line 14 you will get a compiler error, since the Write method is defined on the pointer to the Buffer not on the Buffer itself.
Lookup how interfaces work in Go and how pointers work (http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions)

Comment: @dave-cheney don't understand your edit: 
runeBytes [utf8.UTFMax]byte and
bootstrap [64]byte are clearly arrays to me

Answer (score 2):

It is initialized. When you do not specifically initialize a variable, go will initialize it to its [zero value](http://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value). That means all the internal fields of a `bytes.Buffer` gets the value 0, or similar for the relevant types (e.g. nil for pointers).

The authors then implemented `bytes.Buffer` so all values being 0 is a meaningful starting point(It means [an empty buffer](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer)), so programmers doesn't need to explicitly initialize it in order to start using a Buffer.

Comment: This is a common idiom in Go. Because everything is initialized to zero new types can be made aware of that and treat the zero value as meaningful.

Comment: @Innominate not everything in Go is initialized: maps have no zero type, also pointers are nil by default.

Comment: @metakeule nil is a valid pointer value (it's the zero value for pointers), and maps are pointers, so they are technically initialized to their zero value.

Comment: @weberc2 Yes, but to *use* a map you will have to initialize it (you act on maps as if they were no pointers as with slices).

Comment: @metakeule I understand, but it is initialized nonetheless. It's just not initialized to a particularly useful value. The significance is that it's not whatever arbitrary data happened to be in that spot in memory, so if it's going to break because it wasn't initialized _correctly_ it will do so every time and rather predictably.

Comment: @weberc2 Ok, I get your point now. My point was to help a newbee not making wrong assumptions... ;-)

Comment: @metakeule I understand and appreciate that. I think it's useful for a newbie to know that "zero-value initialization" doesn't mean that it's a ready-to-use object, but rather that it's simply guaranteed to not be garbage data.

Answer (score 0):

This due to the fact that when you call the `Fprintf` method, the `bytes.Buffer.Write` method is implicitely called, and as per the [doc](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.Write):

> Write appends the contents of p to the buffer, growing the buffer as needed.

If you look at the source code, `Write` calls the grow function: `func (b *Buffer) grow(n int) int`.

This function recognizes that the buffer is empty, because it assumes that an empty buffer has 0 values for its internal fields, which is actually how a `bytes.Buffer` structure is initialized by default, just like every structure in go.